# SQL Query to strip of time part using DateAdd()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I searched online and don't get proper answers to my need. 
Basically, with below in my query am getting output in Date column as

```
WHERE DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
```

Output:

```
Date: 2017-12-1 00:00:00:00
```

I don't want to see those 0s at all and just want pure date value present.

my date column should only show me date and nothing for time, not even 0s

Comment: Hi. "I searched" Maybe you should have spelled 'strip off' correctly? Nope--just googling your title with a typo still gives answers. Seems you didn't look very hard. Please read the edit help for ways to format code. Also please tag correctly--including your particular SQL. In fact please read [ask] its links. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 0):

if your system knows Dateadd, it will know datepart as well. If this does not work for you, just cast the date to a string and use substring methods to provide the first few characters only.

To add: I believe, your function would return

```
2017-12-01 00:00:00:00
```

but this is a minor detail...

Comment: hey am new to sql, so could you please pass me detailed steps how to do?
is it like this? 
WHERE CAST(DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())) ??

Comment: datepart? how to use it?